# How to configure Xdebug for multiple users on a local machine?

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, cpanel, xdebug, xdebug-3

I have a new installation of Centos 7 running cPanel and WHM on an AWS EC2 instance.  All software is the latest versions.

I used WHM to setup 5 users, which in turn creates linux users with their own home directory and their own public_html directories.  Then I have enabled MATE Desktop and Tigervnc so each developer can connect to the machine in a vnc session.

So basically this setup is 5 linux users with their own apache vhosts, running their IDE on the same local server.

I then installed Xdebug using pecl and now I want to setup VSCode on each persons account to use Xdebug.  I am also using opcache.

When trying to use VSCode, it seems like we can get the debugger to work, but there is no output in the console of VSCode.  I installed the php-debugger extension in VSCode.

Also we seem to have a problem with VSCode not able to handle include/require statements.  It always says that they cannot be found.  But the files are indeed there and indeed have the correct permissions to be read/written.

I am not really sure how to configure Xdebug and VSCode to get them to work for all local developers with VSCode.  Will what I am doing even work?  Do I need remote connections?  Do I need a DBGp proxy?  Does Xdebug only allow one debugging session at a time?  Do I need to install Xdebug for each user?

Can anyone provide some directions on how to set this up?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

> Will what I am doing even work?

Likely :-)

> Do I need remote connections?

On the Xdebug side, it does not matter whether it's "remote" or on the same machine, in both cases a TCP/IP connection is used. The "remote" in "remote debugger" was always a bad choice of words by the Xdebug developer (me).

> Do I need a DBGp proxy?

You don't *need* it. What you need to be able to do is to have each user initiate a debugging session to their own IDE. As everything runs on the same machine, you can't just reuse ports. Xdebug always connects to the same configured port (`9003` by default).

There are two alternatives:

1. Use a the [DBGp proxy](https://xdebug.org/docs/dbgpProxy) to direct incoming connections from the Xdebug port to registered IDEs. Each of these IDEs will have registered their key with the proxy, so the proxy knows where to forward the request to. You will need to use a [browser extension](https://xdebug.org/docs/step_debug#web-application) so that each developer can set their own unique IDE key as the Xdebug session (cookie) value.
2. Use [Xdebug Cloud](https://xdebug.cloud), which would handle the complicated proxy set-up for you, and the developers only have to set their IDE Key (or now, Cloud key) through the browser extension again, as well as in their IDE. Only PhpStorm supports this for now. There is [configuration documentation available](https://xdebug.cloud/docs).

> Does Xdebug only allow one debugging session at a time?

No. Xdebug supports one debugging connection per PHP request, but IDEs might not accept more than one incoming connection. Both PhpStorm and VS Code's Debug Plugin don't have this problem.

> Do I need to install Xdebug for each user?

No. Xdebug is installed as part of PHP, and as you've only got one PHP installation, having Xdebug available as part of the is enough.